# проблема с новым pdf в общей папке

Tags: windows, pdf

В windows 7 между несколькими компьютерами есть общая папка. Все файлы видны с другого компьютера, открываются и т.д. Проблема возникает когда при помощи сканера через canon mf scan utility в ней создается новый пдф.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он создается защищенным и его приходится разблокировать вручную.Если создавать его в другой папке, то все нормально. В настройках cannon mf таких настроек на нашел. Проблема возникла (как говорят) после того, как был поставлен акробат ридер, потом был удален, до этого было все нормально.

Comment: Super User для кого создали?

Comment: эмм... если честно, то не совсем понимаю о чем вы) дополнительных пользователей не создавали. Захожу под админом

Comment: это сообщество такое

Comment: я захожу под пользователем у которого есть права администратора.

Comment: https://superuser.com

Comment: Удаление и повторное создание папки пробовали? Права на папку проверяли?

Comment: @Alex78191, их вопросы являются тематическими и у нас. Зачем посылать в англоязычное сообщество?

Comment: @Qwertiy на ruSO разрешены только вопросы по программированию и администрированию, а не по любым приложениями.

Comment: @Alex78191, настройка прав доступа к файлам - это как бы администрирование ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся:

к проектированию, использованию и администрированию баз данных;
к настройке физических и виртуальных серверов, серверов-приложений, серверов баз данных, веб-серверов, файл-серверов, средствам их настройки, мониторинга и автоматизации процессов;